# Using xmstarlet how can I retrieve a value from an XML document and put it into a BASH variable

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

How can I retrieve the value of fooVersion from the XML snippet below and put it into a BASH variable please?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" fooVersion="2.13 r1665067">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, based on my own script:

```
fooVersion=`xmlstarlet sel -T -E utf-8 -t -m /TestPlan -v @fooVersion`
```

See [here for more examples](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416).